# What is an ICAP address?

Tags: addresses, icap, checksum

It appears ethereum is using plain hexadecimal addresses like `0x0092e965928626f8880629cec353d3fd7ca5974f` for now.

I noticed, the ethereum C++ implementation outputs so called ICAP addresses, [check this](https://gavofyork.gitbooks.io/turboethereum/content/ethkey.html) generated by `ethkey`:

```
> ethkey new test
Enter a passphrase with which to secure this account (or nothing to use the master passphrase): 
Please confirm the passphrase by entering it again: 
Enter a hint to help you remember this passphrase: 321 backwards
Created key 055dde03-47ff-dded-8950-0fe39b1fa101
  Name: test
  Password hint: 321 backwards
  ICAP: XE472EVKU3CGMJF2YQ0J9RO1Y90BC0LDFZ
  Raw hex: 0092e965928626f8880629cec353d3fd7ca5974f
```

What is an ICAP address? Are these to be used in future releases like we are used to in Bitcoin? Do they always start with X? Do they have a checksum?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Inter Exchange Client Address Protocol (ICAP) is an [IBAN-compatible](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_Bank_Account_Number) system for referencing and transacting to Ethereum client accounts. ICAP was created to "streamline the process of transferring funds, worry-free between exchanges and, ultimately, make KYC and AML pains a thing of the past" ([Source](https://blog.ethereum.org/2015/03/02/gavs-ethereum-d%CE%BEv-update-v/)). ICAP addresses in Ethereum have built in checksum and always begin with `XE`. The aim is to introduce a new IBAN country code: `XE`, formulated as the Ethereum E prefixed with the "extended" X, as used in non-jurisdictional currencies (e.g. `XBT`, `XRP`, `XCP`).

Currently, TurboEthereum (C++ Ethereum client) has full support for ICAP and Geth (Go Ethereum client) is [getting support for ICAP at version 1.4](https://twitter.com/jeffehh/status/695761551165419520).

More info on the design of ICAP can be [found here](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol).

How to generate an ICAP address can be [found here](https://gavofyork.gitbooks.io/turboethereum/content/ethkey.html).