# What is a "basic ICAP address"?

Tags: addresses, icap

This [answer](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/a/1509/42) mentions a "basic ICAP address".  What is a basic ICAP address and what are its benefits and disadvantages over "regular" ICAP addresses?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A basic ICAP address basicly *is* a regular ICAP address. It's the most simple type of ICAP available consisting only of the account identifyer `XE` and the 31 bytes composed from the raw hex ethereum address.

The direct ICAP address has an IBAN-compatible account identifyer `XE`, a checksum like `73` and the rest of the address is composed of the last 30 bytes of the hex ethereum key. This only works if the first byte of the ethereum key is zero as per [specification](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol).

I guess the more interesting question would be, [what are indirect ICAP addresses](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1609/87)? ;-)

Comment: Actually, ALL Ethereum ICAP addresses start with the "XE" identifier followed by a 2-digit checksum. The difference between basic and direct is only that basic ICAP requires 31 characters after those 4 - which makes it 35 characters long and so "not IBAN compliant".
I would be interested in hearing someone who know such things discuss the ramifications.