# Parity account addresses all having prefix 0x00

Tags: accounts, icap, parity-wallet

After creating multiple new accounts with the Parity wallet (v1.6.6), I notice they all have the address prefix `0x00` (the `0x` part being the obvious hexadecimal prefix), for example `0x00A85d2d62E1851ad5702e31619B10c7E4308522`. What is the reason behind this address scheme?

Comment: How many times did this happen? When you say "they all have" how many do you mean? Just curious. The address you provided is 20 bytes long, so it looks legit. (The '0x' is not part of the address as you suggest.)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

This is to follow the [proposed design](https://github.com/ethereum/wiki/wiki/ICAP:-Inter-exchange-Client-Address-Protocol#proposed-design) of IBAN-compatible Ethereum addresses. (See also [What is an ICAP address?](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/q/1085/87))

Any *random* 160-bit Ethereum private key can be converted to any *basic* ICAP address. However, not all ICAP addresses are IBANs.

Only *direct* ICAP addresses follow the IBAN definition which includes the identifier, a checksum, and the account:

```
XE73 38O0 73KY GTWW ZN0F 2WZ0 R8PX 5ZPP ZS
```

This, however, limits the length of the underlying private key to 154-bit and thus, the range of compatible Ethereum private keys is limited from `0x0000000000000000000000000000000000000000` [to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ethereumjs-icap#direct-address-generation) `0x03ffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffffff`.

Parity ensures future IBAN compatibility of your addresses by only using addresses from this range (actually only up to `0x00ff...f` for the sake of simplicity). And that's why all addresses start with `0x00...` in your Parity wallet.

*Disclosure: I work for Parity.*

---

Edit: By the way, the same is true for the cpp-ethereum client (eth).